# Kaspersky rescue Disk on USB

Tags: kaspersky, liveusb, rescue-disk

I'm trying to use Kaspersky Rescue Disk from a USB key. I followed [this procedure](https://web.archive.org/web/20121020181146/http://support.kaspersky.com/faq/?qid=208286083) and it works fine but when I restart my computer, instead of getting a GUI I get "GRUB".

I don't know what to do to launch either a scan or the GUI. Could you help me ?

Comment: Do you have GRUB installed on your computer?  It sounds like you need to edit what devices order your computer boots to

Comment: No, it is installed on my USB Key. And it boots on the USB key

Comment: @Florian This youtube tutorial entitled "Run Kaspersky Rescue Disk 10 from USB Flash Drive by Britec" may help http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HjRjslQMFq4

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to use [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to burn the image to an USB key, it automatically takes care of properly set up everything.

[image]

As you can see, you can alternatively select a distribution (including Kaspersky) from the top dropdown box, or manually indicate an existing `.iso` file to burn on the USB key.